# in which file of cpython 3.10.0 contains keywords of python

Tags: python, c, metaprogramming, interpreter, cpython

I wanted to do metaprogramming and modifiyng python interpreter but i can't find file which contains keywords

I tried to search on ChatGPT, Reddit and Google but I got answers wrong

Comment: You mean [the `keyword` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html)? Or something at a lower level?

Comment: Did you check [cpython Git repo](https://github.com/python/cpython) as well?

Answer (score 0):

In the [cpython source](https://github.com/python/cpython), the keywords are found in `Parser/parser.c`, however, that file is generated from the [Pegen tool](https://devguide.python.org/internals/parser/) based on the grammar specification in `Grammar/python.gram`.